# Active Directory inter-domain trust questions to thwart malicious programs

Tags: active-directory

I'll start my question by explaining my situation.

My company has been facing random, but kind-of-periodic, lockouts involving lots (if not all) of accounts. My team had been suspecting that there's some kind of malware and/or hacking tool that has been pulling all user accounts from the AD Domain Controller, and trying brute-force hacking against those accounts.

We *are* currently monitoring all lockout incidents, trying to narrow down the source of the perpetrator.

However, until we actually find -- and persecute -- the perpetrator, there are some activities that really need uninterrupted access, not affected by account lockouts. Let's call these accounts the `overseers`.

What I had in mind to solve this quandary, is to:

1. Create a temporary Domain. Let's call this `d2.company.com` (D-2), while the original afflicted domain is called `d1.domain.com` (D-1)
2. Have D-1 **trust** D-2, but not the other way around (i.e., D-2 doesn't trust D-1)
3. Create some accounts in D-2, and *somehow* grant them the same privileges as the `overseers` account in D-1. [1]

Now, my questions:

A) Will this strategy work?

B) Will the malicious program/malware be able to bruteforce D-2 accounts?

C) Any catch/gotchas I need to be concerned with?

TIA for your help.

[1] Yes, quite possibly I have to create 'Universal' groups and add that to all the relevant Domain Local groups, but that's a tedium I'm perfectly willing to do.

Comment: Do you have audit logging enabled for the Account authentication failures?  Your event logs should point to the source of the auth requests.

Comment: @Cheekaleak yes, but we haven't been lucky yet. The attacks are not continuous, and seems to be spaced, so it's down to perusing the Active Directory events.

Comment: How does your plan help you track down the source of the problem? I'm not understanding exactly how creating a new domain is going to help you in this scenario.

Comment: @joeqwerty The tracking is done by slowly going over the Event Log until we can narrow down the culprit(s). The new domain is just to protect some accounts from being locked out.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the most urgent thing is to get the malware and/or hacker off your network right now of course, but you already know that.

Creating a new domain and evacuating to it every time you encounter some malware or a hacker just doesn't make any kind of sense. What will you do when they start attacking D2? Create a D3? Then a D4 and D5?

But to answer your question, if you need to grant immunity from lockouts to a specific account or group of accounts in your domain, then you create a Fine Grained Password Policy (Password Settings Object) and apply it to that user or group.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770842(v=WS.10).aspx

This requires a domain functional level of 2008 or higher.

Comment: Hmm... that's an interesting solution... although it doesn't directly answer my questions, I'm going to sleep on it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Ok, to directly answer your questions, A = No, B = Yes, C = Yes, *see above for more information